# How can append Json object directly?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, html, jsonp

My json object is

```
var myjson={ "elements" :[{},{},.....]};
```

Now I want to add some more elements with out disturbing the existing elements.

and I dont want to get use the old elements.
I mean dont like this approach

```
var elements=myjson.elements;
elements=elements.concat(newelementslist);
```

Is there any other approach like

```
myjson.elements.append(newelementlist);
```

Please give me a simple solution.

Comment: `Array.prototype.push.apply(myjson.elements, newelementlist)` should work. But the real question is, what is wrong with the `.concat` approach? Edit: of course, without `apply` you would get the `newelementlist` added as a single element, not a list of elements. That makes sense...

Comment: What's wrong with `myjson.elements.concat(newelementlist);` ?

Comment: probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically

Comment: @xdazz In case of using concat I have to get the existing elements. It is not  possible to me. I just want to append directly.

Comment: Where's JSON in your code? All I see is raw JavaScript objects. If it's an object, it cannot be JSON, because JSON is a *string*.

Comment: @vicario look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
myjson.elements.push({newelement:"newelement"});
```